# Juju - cannot create controller on vsphere

Tags: ssh, juju

Creation of controller fails to vsphere using windows juju client;

It creates the VM but when it cannot connect to it Juju errors out due to "Host key verification failed".

#### Error Message

```
ERROR failed to bootstrap model: waited for 20m0s without being able to connect: No RSA host key is known for fe80::250:56ff:fe1a:5fb7 and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

#### Command output

```
Select a cloud [localhost]: vsphere
Enter a name for the Controller [vsphere-DB-Datacenter1]: juju-ctl1
Creating Juju controller "juju-ctl1" on vsphere/DB-Datacenter1
Looking for packaged Juju agent version 2.4.7 for amd64
Launching controller instance(s) on vsphere/DB-Datacenter1...
 - juju-ab09a5-0 (arch=amd64 mem=3.5G) f49-8a71-cb751c5c4ba2/bionic/5113149876294bb99c41afb7ee3972249c0fa5e25ffb3171af4f5556f45a498d.vmdk.tmp: 83.04% (14.1MiB/s)
Installing Juju agent on bootstrap instance
Fetching Juju GUI 2.14.0
Waiting for address
Attempting to connect to 10.0.0.123:22

ERROR failed to bootstrap model: waited for 20m0s without being able to connect: No RSA host key is known for 10.0.0.123 and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a known bug with VSAN backed datastores. Try an NFS one or traditional block (iSCSI should be easy to setup). I had the same issue.